# Which one of this implementation is better?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

Let's assume i have two class; An abstract class "Human" and a concrete class "Student" which extends "Human".

Implementation 1;

```
public abstract class Human {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String location;

public Human()
{
    super("Human");
}
public Human(String firstName,String lastName) {
    super("Human");
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public Human(String firstName,String lastName,String loc) {
    super("Human");
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.location = loc;
}
public String getLocation()
{
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String loc)
{
    this.location = loc;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

}

So "Student" class can call mutual methods as return super.FirstName or set.SetFirstName(String f) etc... But it does not force someone to implement methods so the newcomers don't know how to add new classes. But also, they don't need to implement mutual variables like firstname etc in every child class in these method. They just call super.

Implementation 2;

```
public abstract class Human{

public abstract String getLocation();

public abstract void setLocation(String loc);

public abstract String getFirstName();

public abstract void setFirstName(String firstName);

public abstract String getLastName()

public abstract void setLastName(String lastName);


}
```

With this now newcomer knows what to implement and write. But he/she needs to write more code and implement also etc variables.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define default methods, which are used by one or more derived classes (or maybe even by all) it would be better to implement the method in the abstract class. You definitely want to implement getters and setters for example. This will prevent a lot of code dulication!

If you want to have a different implementation for every subclass you should use abstract methods to make sure that every class gets an own implementation !